# VirtualBoxVM instances and Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, virtualization

I've got a late 2013 Mac Pro running VirtualVM on it. I currently have a couple of VMs, and I'm looking to add a third. When installing the OS, I'm prompted to "Sign in with Your Apple ID". I enter my apple id and password and hit [Continue]. It pops up an error message

```
Create an Apple ID
Cannot create Apple ID

This Mac is no longer eligible to create Apple ID accounts.
Create an AppleID using a different device.

[Back] [Continue]
```

Now I'm a bit flummoxed. I'm not creating a new ID, I'm trying to sign in with an existing ID. What's going on here?

EDIT:

- The VM is running macOS 10.13 High Sierra (64-bit).
- The country I'm choosing is the US in all cases.
- None of the VMs currently have a working Apple ID

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome to Ask Different. Which macOS version does your your VM run? Does the country you choose in Setup Assistant match the country of your Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

If you are signing in on multiple VMs with the same account, Apple's account server may have noticed and stopped you as you have reached the limit for the number of devices on your account.

Check how many devices you have linked to your account by going to https://www.icloud.com and click Settings. Remove some if there are any that you don't use anymore and try again on the VM.

Clicking the 'Sign Out of All Browsers' button may also help as it will deactivate any sign-ins that may still be valid but unused. You'll have to sign in to your other VMs again afterwards however.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. The only device listed is my physical machine. I also tried signing out of all browsers, and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on MacOS Catalina, but simply ignoring it worked. I had to choose to *Set up Apple ID later*, and go into *Settings* and sign into iCloud from there.